# Unity ECS, Initialize a PhysicsColliderKeyEntityPair buffer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-dots

I have an entity with multiple PhysicsCollider that RaiseTriggerEvents only.

*I think I cannot have a child entity that contains a PhysicsCollider IComponentData, so I think I have to use PhysicsColliderKeyEntityPair.*

**How do we initialize a PhysicsColliderKeyEntityPair?**

Here is what I got so far, I am stuck at ColliderKey!

Class

```
public class PrefabsConverter : MonoBehaviour, IDeclareReferencedPrefabs, IConvertGameObjectToEntity
```

The code

```
 var colliderBuffer = em.AddBuffer<PhysicsColliderKeyEntityPair>(thisEntity);

 for (int a = 0; a < enemyComponent.damagableProfile.values.Count; a++)
 {
      var collider = new PhysicsCollider() { Value = enemyComponent.damagableProfile.values[a].ToCollider() };

      colliderBuffer.Add(new PhysicsColliderKeyEntityPair() { Entity = thisEntity, Key = new ColliderKey(???) });
 }
```

Comment: [com.unity.physics](https://github.com/needle-mirror/com.unity.physics/blob/530102a/Unity.Physics.Hybrid/Conversion/BuildCompoundCollidersConversionSystem.cs#L217-L230) package contains samples you can search locally on doing [github search](https://github.com/search?q=PhysicsColliderKeyEntityPair&type=code)

Comment: Would also love to know the answer to this. Couldn't find the exact answer from @AndrewŁukasik comment. Thanks.